# Add image to HTML from a folder from another project?

Tags: html, image

I've two project in the same solution.
I am trying to pick up an image from Webbapplication.csproj och use it on html page of blazor.csproj.

Any idea how to say this to find the way to the folder from another project?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the question. 
In Webbapplication.csproj the image you want to use, is obviously stored in a physical address right?
Just give that physical path (physical address) to the blazor.csproj

Comment: I uploaded an image by Blazor and it put to MVC's folder. And now i want to use the folder to html in Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="h-100 col-md-9 d-sm-none  d-md-flex align-items-end" style="background: url(//images)">
```

A folder namned images in Webbapplication.

Html code can be found in Blazor.csproj.